# finding an approximation for $\cos(1)$ (Explanation of a solution)

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximation

So I want an approximation $C$ for $\cos(1)$ by using the taylor expansion of the Cosinus-function.
How many terms of the taylor expansion and how many decimal places do I need for $$ | C - \cos(1)| < 10^{-4}$$

I will rework the solution because there was a mistake and I want to give a solution which is more detailed.

Comment: What does $rd$ mean?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to mention what $rd$ is: the round function. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) You are correct, either one has to set $x=1$ on the left side, or the middle and right term are missing a factor $x^{2m+2}$, with $0<\nu<x$.

3) Adding smaller quantities repeatedly to $1$ incurs a floating point error of no more than the machine constant $\epsilon$ in each operation. One could argue that the computation of the term gives an relative error of at most $ϵ/2$ and the rounding after addition also at most $ϵ/2$ so that the combined effect is again an error of $ϵ$. As you add $m$ terms, the error of the floating point approximation is at most $mϵ$ larger than the error of the Taylor polynomial.